# how to make condition on selection of checkbox in user controler

Tags: jquery

I have a user control:

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" />  
 <label>&nbsp;</label>  
<fieldset class="clearfix" id="fieldset-exception">
    <legend>Student Information</legend>
    <div class="fiveper">
        <label for="StudentID">
            Exception ID:
            <span><%=Html.EditorFor(x => x.studentid)%></span>
        </label>
        <label for="Classroom">
            Origination:
            <span><%=Html.EditorFor(model => model.Classroom)%></span>
        </label>
        <label for="Subject">
            Age:
            <span><%=Html.EditorFor(model => model.subject)%></span>
        </label>
</div>
 $('#btnAll').click(function() {
           $('#Details input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        });
```

I am checking all checkboxes using above code
but I need to make condition here that user need to select at least one checkbox to do something?

I have other button to go other page based on this checkbox checked?

can anybody tell me how to check that and how to make that condition here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
if ($("#Details input[@type=checkbox][@checked]").length < 1){
     return false;
}
```

have your button's onclick call this method, and only submit if it doesn't return false.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
if ( $('#Details input[@type=checkbox][@checked]').length < 1 ) {
    //error
}
```

youll also want to implement this server-side as well.